# Different soccer pairings in quarter finals - check my solution

Tags: combinatorics

"How many different pairings are possible in the quarter finals of a world cup where 32 teams participate in?"

Is my solution correct?

Let $\Omega:=\{\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}\times \{\omega_3, \omega_4\}\times \{\omega_5, \omega_6\}\times \{\omega_7, \omega_8\} :\text{$\omega_i \in \{\mathrm{Team}_1, ..., \mathrm{Team_{32}}\}$ and $\omega_i \neq \omega_j$ with $i\neq j$}\}$

So all possibilities are: $\vert \Omega \vert= {32 \choose 2} \cdot {30 \choose 2} \cdot {28 \choose 2} \cdot {26 \choose 2}$

Maybe someone has a different approach?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost right, but I'd say that you need to divide by $4!$ to get the right answer (you only care about how they are partitioned, not the order). You enumerated the set whose elements are tuples of the form ${\color{red}(}\{\omega_1,\omega_2\},\{\omega_3,\omega_4\},\{\omega_5,\omega_6\},\{\omega_7,\omega_8\}{\color{red})}$, as opposed to *sets* of the form ${\color{red}\{}\{\omega_1,\omega_2\},\{\omega_3,\omega_4\},\{\omega_5,\omega_6\},\{\omega_7,\omega_8\}{\color{red}\}}$.

(By dividing by $4!$, you are grouping all such tuples into an equivalence class, effectively treating them as a set.)

So the right answer is actually $\frac1{4!}\binom{32}8\binom{30}6\binom{28}4\binom{26}2$.

---

Alternatively, if you insist on another approach, you can first choose the 8 teams ($\binom{32}8$) and subsequently partition them, which can be done in $\binom 82\binom 62\binom 42\binom 22$ ways. Again here, you need to divide by $4!$ since you don't care about the order in which they are partitioned.

So the answer by this method $\frac1{4!}\binom{32}8\binom 82\binom 62\binom 42\binom 22$.